# How to calculate overlap area of two polygons?

Tags: postgis, polygon, coordinates, area, overlapping-features

I am a beginner in the world of GIS.

I have one table polygons with each polygon having north-east and south-west coordinates. And for every polygon, I need to find area of overlap with other polygons (e.g. 70% area of polygon A overlaps with polygon B).

I know the ST_Intersects function, but it returns boolean. What other function that I can use with putting buffer as 70%?

If anybody could get me started, that would be great!

Comment: What technology are you using? SQL Server? PostGIS? Oracle? Desktop GIS of some sort?

Comment: @AlexLeith this question is tagged with PostGIS, so that would be a fair assumption.

Comment: @EvilGenius - ah, good point...

Answer (score 8):

ST_Intersection(geomA, geomB) returns a geometry, then calculate areas with ST_Area.